# Alternative to Jumploader

Tags: javascript, java, php, upload, image-uploading

I've been using the very well made Jumploader for image uploading and processing for a few years now on our local intranet. We use it to upload images from a compactflash card to the server... and while it's uploading 1) make two different sized thumbnails of the images while uploading and 2) watermark one of the images with a simple transparent PNG file. Unfortunately with the disabling of NPAPI in Chrome it's forced us to use Internet Explorer to use Jumploader and with the newest versions of Java it's all but disabled the Java applet because it is so out of date and expired. The maker of Jumploader has completely abandoned the project a few years ago and the forums on the jumploader website are completely spam filled.

So my question is this... is there an alternative to Jumploader that does this:

1. Uploads the full images (JPG) to a specified location. The file
   names need to be settable when uploading.
2. Creates two specific sized thumbnails, one of which needs an
   overlayed transparent PNG watermark.
3. It does all this in about 5 seconds or less each image (if
   possible)

The only alternative I've really seen at this point is making it myself, which I'm not as familiar with Java as I am PHP. Doing this all in PHP would take way more than 5 seconds... a LOT more from my initial testing plus when you upload an image via php we've noticed that it often strips the metadata and color profile from the jpg images when uploading. If it has to be two different javascripts/applets that run that's fine, though I'm hoping there's another 'all in one' out there somewhere.

Thanks all!

Comment: Hi Britt, Any luck?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @user648026, but nothing yet. I'm still hunting for an alternative.

Comment: @PhotographerBritt Very late to the party but have you tried [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com) ? It can rename your files and I believe also copies which can then be resized (`transformFile` config option). Not sure about thumbnails, but worth looking into anyway, in case anyone is interested.

Comment: @Pawel I have indeed just recently, and I have only really just started to really crack it open. It's a lot tougher to get it to do what Jumploader did really easy but I think it's the only option at this point. I wish there was an easy to pull up a client side directory tree like Jumploader did, but only applets seem to be able to do that for browser safety. So it's pretty close, just takes a long time to really get it to do what you want/need.